# ReactJS - Dispatch in componentDidMount and use Redux prop in render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

«Hello guys!»

In `componentDidMount` I dispatch an action that changes my redux prop id, but on render, the prop id from redux state is null.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

```
componentDidMount() {
    const{match:{params:{roomId}}, getItem, getDirectInfo, getIndirectInfo, getType} = this.props;
    if(roomId !== undefined) {
      const type = getType(roomId);
      if(type.data === 'DIRECT') getDirectInfo(roomId).then(roomId => getInfo(roomId));
      else if(type.data === 'INDIRECT') getIndirectInfo(roomId).then(roomId => getInfo(roomId));
    }
 }
```

getInfo changes the value of prop "id", but on render it is null

Comment: Put some code.It won't be possible otherwise

Comment: You should provide an example of the problem you're facing. Without an example advice is limited to making guesses about your code.

Comment: I think it is pretty simple... in componentDidMount I call getSomething() that changes the prop "id" from redux (which is initialized with null)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably null because you initialize it to null in your reducer, and the dispatch haven't been called yet when `render()` is called.

Comment: After it is dispatched it should be rerendered, where it should not be null

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the problem is a error because you try to use the id but it is undefined.

In the react lifecycle, the `render()` function is called before `componentDidMount()`. Meaning that you should be able to handle an id that is undefined when rendering, I suggest showing a loading indicator of some kind.

Since you didn't show a complete example that reproduces this, there could also be other problems, make sure the reducer actually works and your component is properly connected.